# Windows - Enable Device Encryption for Home version

Tags: windows, encryption, windows-11, bitlocker

I have a Windows 11 Home edition which is **not a laptop** and I need to have my Hard-Drive encrypted.

The issue is that `BitLocker` is only available for Win Professional edition.
I've found our the `Device Encryption` feature under all Windows editions but I cannot enable it (it does not appear under `Update & Security`.

I've found out using the `System Information` tool under `Device Encryption Support` that I have an issue, here it is :

> Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: Hardware Security Test
> Interface failed and device is not Modern Standby, Un-allowed DMA
> capable bus/device(s) detected

I've looked up a bit, changed some registry settings but nothing changed. From GUI to command line, nothing made it work.

I also tried to enabled `Modern Standby` but didn't work.

Edit :

- This is the [link](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/windows-11-home-tpm-encryption.6092/page-2) I've followed to enable `Modern Standby`, Option 1 & 2 tested
- I've also tried [this](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/check-modern-standby-mode-on-windows-10/) :

Comment: please edit your question to include - the "registry settings" you tried changing; the actions you took in GUI and command line; whether you enabled Modern Standby or you tried and failed to enable it? -- this information will help others avoid mentioning actions that you have already taken, and maybe help you try things differently

Comment: Did this laptop come with Windows 11? Device Encryption has come enabled on Windows 10 devices for several years now.  That policy extends to Windows 11 devices.

Comment: You have Win11 NOT running on your laptop? Why do you have to have encryption? What have you changed?

Comment: I've edited my question by adding Modern Standby attemps. It is not a laptop indeed, it's a PC that was running Win10 that I upgraded to Win11 (when it was available in 2021).
This is a compliance requirement that I need to follow to pass a certification on my own

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to activate Moden Standby with a desktop CPU and chipset. If you need to to be compliant for someone (like your employer) you know who you can ask to pay for the upgrade to Win11 Pro.